# How Do I create a Data Validation List based on a filtered TABLE?

Tags: excel, validation, dynamic, autofilter

I have spent hours searching for an answer and attempted to create my own solution with little pieces of information I gleaned, but I am still no closer to a solution.

Scenario: I have a data table (sorted by index field that I want to use).  I have a CRITERIA column and the INDEX column. I have a form worksheet where I want the list to appear. On a second form worksheet I have VBA code attached to a button(s) that filters the data table in-place. On the form sheet there is a SELECTION CRITERIA field that, based on the value selected from the pull-down 'data validation' menu, dynamically populates the form fields from the values on the corresponding row in the data table. (this is accomplished by a VBA event trigger to the cell, and population is accomplished with other VBA code.  The event trigger also prompts user to write changes back to the data table if changes are identified from the previous populated form.)

PROBLEM: I want the data validation list on the SELECTION CRITERIA cell to dynamically change based upon the auto-filter triggered by the button selection.  (each button runs a VBA procedure that filters the list based upon one or more criteria)

I am most grateful for any suggestions or solutions provided!

Comment: Do you have a sample sheet or examples of what you are looking for the solution to look like? This may [help](https://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal13.html) . Are you looking for a VBA/userform solution or a formula solution?

Comment: The current data is sensitive so I will have to mock something up to show an example.The form/report is simply an excel worksheet, as it is a long form with a lot of data pulling from multiple tables.  a userform would be more confusing and complicated for my users..